# hypertable thrift or swig question

Tags: go

I'm very interested in Hypertable DB, and im currently developing a crawler and indexer in Go-lang, unfortunately there's no binding available for the languange. I'm having a difficulties in compiling swig and hypertable c++ client (too many errors) and thrift don't have a working support for go-lang, is there a way to connect directly to hypertable's thriftbroker by straightforward coding from go? or any suggestion to access hypertable from go?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

There may not be Thrift support in Go, but it appears there will soon be Go support in Thrift:
https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/THRIFT-625

It appears that the code from [this standalone project](https://github.com/pomack/thrift4go) has been checked into the trunk of Thrift, and will appear in some future release (maybe version 0.7).   One of those two (the development version of Thrift or the standalone project should get you started).